# Any tool is available to modify the strings in resources file from the specified dll

Tags: c#-4.0

Any tool is available to modify the strings in resources file from the specified .dll.

Comment: Do you mean to update the DLL or as an additional set for localization?

Comment: exactly i shld update older string to newer string

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own by loading the assembly then get the resource manager from it

```
var myType = Type.GetType("ViewRes.StaticMessages", true); 
var myResManager = new ResourceManager("StaticMessages", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(myType));
```